# How to link to openssl on windows in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

This has been driving me crazy.

I have a cmake library that requires openssl. When compiling on Windows 10, using

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED
```

Fails because I have not installed OpenSSL of course.. But how do you even install OpenSSL so that it is accessible for cmake?

Looking at their webpage I can only find a couple of tar.gz files to download, so I assume that is for linux. And looking at the [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) it is not even a cmake project.

There is a github repository that titles itself as openssl with cmake, but I have no idea how that works.

So my question is:
How do I download OpenSSL source/libs and add it to my project so that cmake can find it? I would very much prefer to build it from source and with the source added to the project to avoid installation hustle for future developers. Is there a `fetch_content` command that can download it?

Any example cmake code would be much appreciated.

Comment: [https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-WINDOWS.md](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-WINDOWS.md) may help.

Comment: The question primary looks like "Where to **download** or **install** OpenSSL for Windows?". In that case CMake is out of scope. If you have already downloaded/installed OpenSSL, then just specify `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` variable to point to that installation, and `find_package(OpenSSL)` will be able to find it.

Comment: The install procedure could be different between using mingw or msvc. For mingw you can switch to use msys2 and install it via the package management that is in msys2

Comment: But how to install it for msvc then? I don't know why but I cannot find anything that seems relevant @Tsyvarev

Comment: I mean, install with develepment files that is, so that you can set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR and build with it. Btw, I'm using msvc but would also like to know how to do mingw

Comment: If you use msys2 for mingw the install command is in this link: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl type `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl` in the msys2 shell